# Flutter ios build for testing

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I would Like to know how I can build a release app without registering it to the app store. I would Like to have the APK file and share it with friends for testing purposes without registering the app. Cant find information connected with this.
Thanks!

UPDATE:
Found solution for getting .ipa file which was installed with Cydia Impactor on a real device:

```
# flutter build
flutter build ios --release --no-codesign

# make folder, add .app then zip it and rename it to .ipa
mkdir -p Payload
mv ./build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app Payload
zip -r -y Payload.zip Payload/Runner.app
mv Payload.zip Payload.ipa

# the following are options, remove Payload folder
rm -Rf Payload
```

Comment: thx for update, really helpful

Comment: I can share IPA file only with www.diawi.com or any type of sharing? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow this article to make .ipa file. (.apk is for android only, for iOS it's .ipa)

> [https://medium.com/mλgnξtλr/how-to-export-a-ipa-file-from-xcode-without-a-dev-account-bac8b2645ad3](https://medium.com/m%CE%BBgn%CE%BEt%CE%BBr/how-to-export-a-ipa-file-from-xcode-without-a-dev-account-bac8b2645ad3)

Keep in mind that, apple is signing build to be installed on real devices, so you have to turn that off, and after making an ipa file, you can upload it to www.diawi.com and get link from there to share it with your friend. This diawi links are not working some times, in that case you can use cydiaimpector tool for installing the build.

For this installation, your friend has to put their apple id and password upon requested, here NOTE that if your two factor authentication is ON, then you have to create app specific password to be entered in.

> How to create app-specific password?
>
> https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiSvpjUo-fjAhXt8XMBHRtBDlUQFjACegQIDBAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.imore.com%2Fhow-generate-app-specific-passwords-iphone-ipad-mac&usg=AOvVaw3chF3FoIcfHZLR6jExh_EZ

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Although the approach described in the medium article didn't work I figured it out how to generate .ipa file and using the Cydia Impactor it worked as expected.